# Errors when trying to open object in VS Design Surface

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When trying to design an object I get this error:

```
...no suitable method found to override.
```

I also get the following warnings:

```
Warning 2   The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. The designer inspected the following classes in the file: 

    Thing --- The base class 'System.Object' cannot be designed.
    Form1 --- The base class 'System.Object' cannot be designed.
```

Comment: What "codes"? Can you post an example of the code that you wrote which doesn't compile?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have created a class called `Form1` that doesn't derive from Form.

You probably have something like this:

```
class Form1
{
    // etc...
}
```

Instead of:

```
class Form1 : Form
{
    // etc...
}
```

This might also explain why the overrides failed.

Answer (score 1):

The base class of your Form1 should be System.Windows.Forms.Form, not System.Object.

Answer (score 0):

Without any context, we can't provide any really meaningful answers. You should really read up on object-oriented development and what method overriding actually means, but the short version is that you have a function in your code that has the `override` modifier attached to it, but none of its base classes define a function with the same signature marked as `virtual` (in this specific case, they don't define a member with that signature at all).

The second error is too generic to even take a guess.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

I had faced similar issue and resolved after adding this.

HTH.